# Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : RHS of assignment to existing column 'RAD3' is zero length but not NULL

Tags: r, data.table

I have various data folders, one folder per city. In each folder, there are various txt files. A small sample of one of my txt files is as follows:

```
/* DESCRIPTION:
Algorithm
Parameter(s):   D/T
Constant [m**2]
Radiation1 [W/m**2] (RAD1)
Radiation1 Quality code (RAD1Qc)
Radiation2 [W/m**2] (RAD2)
Radiation2 Quality code (Rad2Qc)
Radiation3 [W/m**2] (RAD3)
*/
D/T Constant [m**2] RAD1 [W/m**2]   RAD1Qc  RAD2 [W/m**2]   RAD2Qc  RAD3 [W/m**2]
1996-02-01S00:00:00 2.385024    15  0   23  0  40
1996-02-01S00:01:00 2.385024    26  0   24  0  34
1996-02-01S00:02:00 2.385024    19  1   12  1  
1996-02-01S00:03:00 2.385024        1   11  0  
1996-02-01S00:04:00 2.385024    1   0   -21 1  
1996-02-01S00:05:00 2.385024    -20 2   -2  2
1996-02-01S00:06:00 2.385024    251 0   0   4
...
...
```

I am using a code where I want to count number of NAs in RAD3 column. The condition of a cell of RAD3 being considered as NA is if either of RAD1 or RAD2 is NA, then RAD3 will be NA. The code is mentioned below.

```
rm(list = ls())

# Load required libraries
library(data.table)

# Set your working directory
setwd("F:/Folder1")

# Read the files
read_the_files <- function(filelist){
  lapply(filelist, function(file) {
    fread(file, skip = "D/T\tConstant [m**2]")             
  })
}

# Dealing with Columns
correct_column_names <- function(dt_list){
  dt_list <- lapply(dt_list, FUN = function(x){
    colnames(x) <- gsub(" \\[.*\\]", "", colnames(x))

columns_to_set_zero <- c(
  'RAD1',
  'RAD2',
  'RAD3'
)
x[x$RAD6 > 50, columns_to_set_zero] <- 0   #RAD6 is another column in data

print("After column adjustment")

# Count NAs based on your specified conditions for RAD1 columns
    condition1_Rad1 <- is.na(x$RAD1) | x$RAD1 == ""
    condition2_RAD1 <- x$RAD1Qc != 0
    condition3_RAD1 <- x$RAD1 < -40 & x$RAD1 > 150

# Count NAs based on your specified conditions for RAD2 columns
    condition1_RAD2 <- is.na(x$RAD2) | x$RAD2 == ""
    condition2_RAD2 <- x$RAD2Qc != 0
    condition3_RAD2 <- x$RAD2 < -4 & x$RAD2 > x$250

# Count NAs based on your specified conditions for RAD3 columns
    condition_RAD3 <- ifelse(
    condition1_RAD1 | condition2_RAD1 | condition3_RAD1 | 
    condition1_RAD2 | condition2_RAD2 | condition3_RAD2,
      NA, x$RAD3
    )

# Update the RAD3 column with the new values
    x$RAD3 <- 3

# Count NAs in RAD3 based on the new condition
    na_count_RAD3 <- sum(is.na(x$RAD3))

cat("NA count for RAD3 column: ", na_count_RAD3, "\n")

print("After NA count calculation")

return(list(data = x, na_count_RAD3 = na_count_RAD3))
  })

  return(dt_list)
}

# List of files to read
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

# Read the files
data_list <- read_the_files(files)

# Process and correct column names
processed_data_list <- correct_column_names(data_list)
```

The code has worked well with majority of data folders. But the last line of the above code is giving following error with some folders. Could anyone please help me in resolving the error.

```
Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) :
RHS of assignment to existing column 'RAD3' is zero length but not NULL. If you intend to 
delete the column use NULL. Otherwise, the RHS must have length > 0; e.g., NA_integer_. If you 
are trying to change the column type to be an empty list column then, as with all column type 
changes, provide a full length RHS vector such as vector('list',nrow(DT)); i.e., 'plonk' in 
the new column.
```

Comment: Which line of code produced that error?

Comment: If the error occurs after you read in the data from that text file, then please provide usable data instead of asking us to parse that hard-to-parse data.

Comment: @user2554330 the last of code is producing the error : processed_data_list <- correct_column_names(data_list)

Comment: @r2evans what is mean by usable data? While reading the data, I have removed all the initial rows before '*/' and considered all the data afterwards.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code in that function.  How can we tell you how to fix it if we can't see it?

Comment: @user2554330 I have added the complete code now. The last line of code producing the error. Hope it is visible now.

Comment: @AlexiakBoston, I mean ... I'm not going to spend time trying to solve an unrelated problem of how to import _that_ data given that apparently you have already solved it. It's not just a simple `read.table(.., header=TRUE)`, so you have obviously done something else, perhaps as `read_the_files(..)`, I don't know. I won't work on problems where the issue is not abundantly clear looking at the code, so ... _usable data_. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 for examples of using `dput`.

Comment: AlexiakBoston, have you resolved this problem?